# setting vnc password in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf breaks cockpit vnc console

Tags: server, virtualization, vnc, kvm-virtualization, cockpit

Have a working installation of ubuntu server 20.04 with kvm/qemu and cockpit web-based interface. I want to use both cockpit browser based vnc console and external vnc desktop viewers (krdc and remmina).

The problem is when I set the `vnc_password` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` to allow external vnc viewers to connect, it breaks the browser based vnc console.

When I disable `vnc_password` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` the browser based vnc console works but all external vnc viewers are refused.

**Vnc web console with password enabled in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` shows connecting but does not load.**
[image]

**Vnc web console with password disabled in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` allows connection.**
[image]